# Enable "Try it out" in OpenAPI so that no need to click

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm using FastAPI and OpenAPI/Swagger UI to see and test my endpoints.

Each time I use an endpoint for the first time, in order to test it, I have to first click the <kbd>Try it out</kbd> button, which is getting tedious.

Is there a way to make it disappear and be able to test the endpoint instantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the OpenAPI/swagger page by passing a dictionary to the kwarg `"swagger_ui_parameters"` when creating your `FastAPI` instance ([docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#configuring-swagger-ui)). The full list of all settings you can update that way can be found [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration).

For your example, it would look like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_parameters={"tryItOutEnabled": True})
```